# Serialization issue : de.ruedigermoeller

Tags: java, swing, serialization, javafx

Trying to get https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization framework as drop in replacement for my JVM serializer. As a first step.

Here is my serializer:

```
static FSTConfiguration conf = FSTConfiguration.createDefaultConfiguration();

public Serialiser() {
    conf.registerClass(MapSerializableForm.class, // etc// ...
}

public byte[] serialise(Object obj) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final FSTObjectOutput o = new FSTObjectOutput(b);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        bytes = b.toByteArray();
        b.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bytes;
}

public Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
    Object deser = null;
    try {
        final ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        final FSTObjectInput o = new FSTObjectInput(b);
        deser = o.readObject();
        b.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return deser;
}
```

The class that is causing me problems is this one: I'm wrapping JavaFX images with Swing images to help me serialise them. My code does work with the standard Java serializer, but is v. slow. I'm hopeful for improvements, if I can get it working. The result is a nullpointerException during deserialization. It's late, here, but I've tried to be clear.

```
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

public class SerializableImage implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7984341875952256208L;
public transient Image image ;

public SerializableImage(Image image) {
    this.image=image;
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    s.defaultReadObject();
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(s); //image comes back null !
    image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
    s.defaultWriteObject();
    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", s);
}

public double getWidth() {
    return image.getWidth();
}
```

In the readObject method, (inside the stream "s") I'm able to see an incoming FSTObjectInput with a wrappedStack of one object: this as hoped contains a SerializableImage in the "toRead" field. However, I'm uncertain how to get this out and into my BufferedImage:

```
 BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(s);
```

Hence, currently, the image comes back null. I tried adding an FSTInput, but couldn't get it to work. Thanks for any help.